# How to use Black-Scholes' formula for a butterfly option?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, option-strategies

I'm wondering if I can apply Black-Scholes formula to value a butterfly option, i.e: $$B(T)=V_\text{call}(S(T)-K,0)+V_\text{call}(S(T)-K',0)-2V_\text{call}(S(T)-K'',0)$$ with $K<K''<K'$, just evaluating each call with B-S formula and operating independently. I think so but I don't know how to explain it with a theoretical basis.

Comment: What do you mean you can't explain? We can always hedge a portfolio of vanilla options just like how we would do it for one.

Comment: The value of a set of options is the sum of the values of the individual options, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

As barrycarter stated in the comment - the value of a set of [European!] options is the sum of the values of the individual options. This is simply follows from integral of a sum being a sum of integrals.

$$butterfly\,option\,price = \\
\int_0^\infty butterfly\,payoff(S) dS =  \\
\int_0^\infty (call\,payoff(S,K)+call\,payoff(S,K')+call\,payoff(S,K''))  dS  = \\
\int_0^\infty call\,payoff(S,K) dS + \int_0^\infty call\,payoff(S,K') dS + \int_0^\infty call\,payoff(S,K'') dS = \\
call(K)+call(K')+call(K'')
$$

Comment: The value of a portfolio of non-European options is also the sum of the individual values.